# HTML5 Swiffy with a Swf Fallback

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy

I have a .swf-to-Swiffy HTML5 banner and would like to create a .swf fallback for IE.  What is the proper way to do this?  I currently have the Swiffy inside an iframe (yikes).

Comment: Check the user agent, if IE then write a Flash object, otherwise write that Swiffy iframe.

Comment: I added the `html` and `flash` tags to your question.  Since these tags are a bit more general, they should give your question more attention.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog post here that may help
http://www.malphursinteractive.com/flash-to-html5-fallback/

Essentially the idea is to use CSS conditionals to load the relevant javascript depending on the browser e.g.

```
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/swiffy.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/animation.js"></script>
    <!-- <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.embedSWF("images/animation.swf", "swiffycontainer", "300", "390", "9.0.115");
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

The 'swiffy.js' is the Google Swiffy library, the 'animation.js' contains the specific animation javascript created by exporting Flash to Swiffy. These are loaded for **NON IE** browsers.

The 'swfobject.js' is loaded and embed code is run for IE browsers to display a Flash fallback.

You then have a div in your page to hold the animation and target it with the 'swfobject.embedSWF' code.

```
<div id="swiffycontainer"></div>
```

You can also provide a Non flash fallback with CSS e.g.

```
#swiffycontainer{
 width: 300px;
 height: 390px;
 background: url('../images/animation.gif') no-repeat no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
```

}

Hope that helps.

Comment: Link rot happens. Please sum up or quote the crucial bits here. Link-only answers are subject to deletion without further notice.